# Can't type text into UITextField or UITextView in iOS6

Tags: iphone, uitextfield, uitextview, ios6, first-responder

In one of my apps, when I try to edit (type some text) `UITextField`, `UITextView` or any other 'text-able' `UIControl` the cursor just blinks but **no characters are typed in** except BACKSPACE (possible only when I have some initial text in it), RETURN and switching character types. This goes to all controls across whole application.

Summary:

1. It happens only from iOS 6.0 (does not occur on iOS 5.x, 4.x neither Simulator or real device)
2. All delegate methods are fired (shouldBeginEditing: didBeginEditing:) **except** shouldChangeCharactersInRange:
3. isFirstResponder flag is behaving set correctly (shouldBeginEditing: logs NO, while didBeginEditing: logs YES correctly). It is also tested using logs that THE firstResponder IS the one already edited.
4. **It repairs itself after** any `UIAlertView` is presented to the user and dismissed. It doesn't matter if this alert is shown on the same screen (UIViewController view) or any other.

I have no idea how to even approach or debug this.

Where should I look for hints? Any experts of tracking responder chain related issues etc.?

How can I track down the `UIAlertView`'s effect on the issue?

Comment: Posting this questions inspired me somehow and I found the solution. It was pretty trivial. Shall I wait and give you guys a chance to gain some points or shall I post an answer straight away?

Comment: here is another solution:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12447875/keyboard-and-cursor-show-but-i-cant-type-inside-uitextfields-and-uitextviews/12559046#12559046

Comment: Please post your solution, I have tried everything and it still will not work. Makekeyandvisible is not the only reason why this can happen.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Depending on your implementation it's either the `makeKeyAndVisible` method of the `UIWindow` class that you forgot to call inside the `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` method of the application delegate or corresponding `Visible at Launch` flag in your main interface xib file.

Cheers... :)

Comment: Yes, that was exactly it. I have also added window.rootViewController = ... just in case. Looks like iOS 6 relies on those settings more than previous releases.

Comment: Or maybe on the contrary the previous versions of the iOS were making that call for you...

Comment: Yes, I've recently set window.rootViewController too, to fix a warning log message that appeared on startup. I've just figured out that the way I did it before (adding the view of my rootViewController as subview to the window) didn't have the UITextField flaw. However, I don't recommend to go back to this old method of adding the rootViewController. Use window.rootViewController and fix the issue as described here.

Comment: Hi, I am having 6 UITextField. out of which only one is behaving weirdly ( the cursor just blinks but no characters are typed in except BACKSPACE in the same way as described in question). Please suggest any other solution.

Answer (score 2):

in my case, there is a 'visible at launch' on the main window, it was unchecked, which works on iOS5 only, needs to check it to make it working on iOS6.

Answer (score 0):

In my situation I had an activity indicator that would pop up over the main window during periods of background activity.  In this case the activity indicator view had its own window that was set to UIWindowLevelAlert.  I was inadvertently calling makeKeyAndVisible on this window.  Later on I would call resignKeyWindow.   This used to work on iOS 4 and 5 but no longer worked in iOS 6.  I discovered that this was not technically necessary as simply using window.hidden = Y/N worked just as well.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I moved becomeFirstResponder for my UITextField from ViewDidLoad to ViewDidAppear and this solved my problem.