# UISearchBar not taking keyboard input but accepting Siri input on iOS 6

Tags: ios6, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I wrote some time ago an app using a Navigation Controller. One of the pushed views contains a UISearchDisplayController and a UISearchBar. The code worked perfectly up to iOS 5. If I compile it to target iOS 6, when selecting the search bar the keyboard appears but the search bar does not seem to accept/receive the keyboard input; however it does accept Siri's input and the search is then performed properly. This happens whether or not I set the search bar as the first responder when the view is loaded (ViewDidLoad method). If I recompile the code to target iOS5 it does work again.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same problem similar problem.  In my case the problem was that the window that contains the UISearchBar was not the "key window."  I solved the problem by calling makeKeyWindow on my application delegate's window.

```
[[[MyAppDelegate App] window] makeKeyWindow];
```

Comment: Older iOS templates didn't always include this - make sure you have it as it fixes a few other niggling bugs as well.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12504575/1113385) solution, which worked perfectly for me! This behavior happend with UITextView and UISearchBar. Hope it helps!