# UISearch Bar Not Being Updated By Keyboard Input

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, ios6

I have a ViewController with a subview that contains a `UISearchBar`. When I click on the search bar the keyboard appears and I am able to close it using the cancel button. The problem seems to be that it isn't accepting any of the input when a user clicks on the keyboard buttons.

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark SEARCH METHODS
#pragma mark -


- (BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {

    self.mainSearchBar.showsCancelButton = YES;

    return YES;
}


- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{

    [self.mainSearchBar resignFirstResponder];

    self.mainSearchBar.showsCancelButton = NO;

    self.mainSearchBar.text = @"";

}

- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {

    [self.mainSearchBar resignFirstResponder];

}
```

Has anyone had this issue before or know how to fix it?

** UPDATE ***********

It turns out the Siri will work when trying to edit the UISearchBar. Still no luck with the keyboard input though. I think it has something to do with the fact that the UISearchBar is situated on a UIView that is then added as a subview. Not sure how to fix it though.

** UPDATE 2 ***********
Moved the search box to the main UIView and I am still getting the same error. I am wondering if it is now related to the Navigation Controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, the answer was found on a previous thread [Keyboard and cursor show, but I can't type inside UITextFields and UITextViews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12447875/keyboard-and-cursor-show-but-i-cant-type-inside-uitextfields-and-uitextviews/12504575#12504575)

It turns out that in IOS6 the Visible at Launch check needs to be clicked on the options.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the app delegate has a [self.window makeKeyAndVisible]. Hopefully it will solve your problem.

Comment: Hi, just checked an the delegate does have this method

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have added a UISearchBarDelegate in your viewController's .h file.

Comment: Hi just added the delegate and it hasn't made any difference. Everything works ok apart from the UISearchBar being updated when keys are pressed.

Comment: Try this delegate method:- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{      }

Comment: Just added it and placed an NSLog in there. It does print the log when starting but still no luck with the update.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code also:

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText

{
    NSLog(@"%@",searchText);
}
```

Comment: Hi, this isn't being recognised so nothing is being logged.

Answer (score 0):

This has to be related to how the `SearchBar` is rendered in relation to the `ViewController`'s `view`.  Why are you making the `SearchBar` a `subview` of another `view` rather than a subview of the `ViewController`'s `view`?

Comment: I have a UIView that sits at the bottom. I then have a UIView above that that acts as a menu (think Facebook side menu interface) and then above that I have a UIView that holds the content and the UISearchBar. The idea is that the top view will slide when the user clicks a button.